# How do I show an input field for each click on a button in react js?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to display an input field for every click on a button "Add Input Field". Now it is showing only one time when I click on button "Add Input Field". How Can I achieve this.

Here below I have created a codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/6lr8w994vn

Comment: are you looking for a solution like this https://codesandbox.io/s/3vqyo8xlx5 ?

Comment: yes I wanted the same @Jayavel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this, you will have to store an array in your state containing the information to generate each field.

Then, in your `add` function, set your array to your deconstructed previous array, and your additional element:

```js
class InputAdder extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            inputs: []
        }
    }

    addInput = ev => {
        this.setState(prev => ({ inputs: [...prev.inputs, 'Hi'] }))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.addInput}>Add input</button>
                {this.state.inputs.map(node => <input type="text"/>)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<InputAdder/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

You will then simply have to map over your array in your `render` function

Comment: You can do this by using a CSS rule, I edited my question to have the `input` displayed as `block`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to store the number of inputs in the state, which will be incremented by one on every click. Then pass this value to props of your component and use map function to create the corresponding number of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, Change your state from this:

```
this.state = {
   add: false,
   addChild: false
};
```

to :

```
this.state = {
  add: [],
  addChild: []
};
```

and in `addInputField` function increase `add` array size every time it clicked, then use this.state.add to render your input fields. Same applies to Child.

Demo Component:

```
class Demo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      add: [],
      addChild: []
    };
  }
  addInputField = event => {
    const add = this.state.add;
    const size = add.length + 1;
    add.push(size);
    this.setState({
      add
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  addChildInputField = event => {
    const addChild = this.state.addChild;
    const size = addChild.length + 1;
    addChild.push(size);
    this.setState({
      addChild
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Grid>
          <Grid>
            <Button onClick={this.addInputField} style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
              {" "}
              <Icon>
                <AddCircle />
              </Icon>{" "}
              Add Input Field
            </Button>
            {this.state.add.map(index => {
              return (
                <Grid>
                  <TextField
                    id="preference"
                    label="Preference"
                    name="points"
                    value={this.state.name}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    margin="normal"
                  />
                  <Button onClick={this.addChildInputField}> Add Child</Button>
                </Grid>
              );
            })}
            {this.state.addChild.map(index => {
              return (
                <Grid style={{ marginLeft: 50 }}>
                  <TextField
                    id="preference"
                    label="Child Preference"
                    name="points"
                    value={this.state.name}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    margin="normal"
                  />
                </Grid>
              );
            })}
          </Grid>
          <Grid>
            <Button
              color="primary"
              variant="contained"
              type="submit"
              style={{ margin: "0.2rem", marginTop: 30 }}
            >
              Save
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Demo;
```

[Full code available here](https://codesandbox.io/s/3vqyo8xlx5)
 Hope it helps.

Comment: @Swati can you check my answer, hope it helps.